# Numerical integration with FFT

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Suppose I am faced with the following integral:

\begin{equation}
F(\bf{x}) = \int \frac{d^{2}\bf{k}}{(2\pi)^{2}} exp(-i\bf{k}\cdot \bf{x})f(\bf{k})
\end{equation}

where $f$ is some (known) function of $\bf{k}$, and $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{k}$ both two-dimensional vectors with the usual interpretation: x is the real space coordinate, k the fourier space coordinate.

To solve this, my first instinct is to use a Fast Fourier Transform. That is, first I make the approximation

\begin{equation}
F(\bf{x}) = \int \frac{d^{2}\bf{k}}{(2\pi)^{2}} exp(-i\bf{k}\cdot \bf{x})f(\bf{k}) \approx \frac{(\Delta k)^{2}}{(2\pi^{2})}\sum exp(-i\bf{k}\cdot\bf{x})f(\bf{k})
\end{equation}

and use the definiton of the forward FFT in [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) to compute this. Note that, in using the forward transform, $\bf{x}$ takes on the role of the harmonic coordinate, and $\bf{k}$ that of the real space coordinate. As such I suppose it doesn't really have a physical interpretation, but for computational purposes it should be fine.

Then I shift the values to have the zero 'frequency' in the center using numpy's fftshift.

Now this seems straightforward enough. I left out most context for supposed clarity, but later on I use this function $F$ as a kernel to convolve an image with. Since a convolution is straightforward enough, I suspect the error must be in the computation of this kernel. In particular, the normalization seems off.

My questions about the above therefore:
**Is the computation above numerically sound? Am I perhaps missing some normalization factors in going from the continuous to discrete FT? Or is there perhaps something intrinsically wrong with what I'm doing?**

Note: "No, what you're doing here seems fine, the error must be somewhere else", is also a valid answer...

(I tried to be as concrete as possible, without having to give the precise context (which is rather involved).)

---

Quick example of the implementation:
First, a snippet of code showing the things I mention above:

```
#First, make the integrand for the kernel
kernel = make_kernel(parameters)

dk = abs(grid.k1[1]) #grid was defined earlier

#Next, compute the integral using the fft, and shift to get zero-centered
K = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(kernel)*dk**2./(2*np.pi)**2.) 

#Get the fourier transform of the kernel, for the convolution
#Amounts to using fft2 once more
K_fourier = np.fft.fft2(K)

#Also compute the FFT of the image, this is also for the convolution
#The 'hanning' filter apodizes the edges for compatibility with FFT
I, mask, lost_power = hanning(image.image,int(30))
Im2_fourier = np.fft.fft2(image2.image)

#Same recipe to 'image3', which is used for a bias term
I, mask, lost_power3 = hanning(deepcopy(image3.image),int(30))
Im3_fourier = np.fft.fft2(image3.image)

#Multipy by a factor for lost power of the apodizing mask
image2.image*=np.sqrt(lost_power)
image3.image*=np.sqrt(lost_power3)

#Compute convolutions using convolution theorem
convolution2 = np.fft.ifft2(Im2_fourier*K_fourier)
convolution3 = np.fft.ifft2(Im3_fourier*K_fourier)

#The desired quantity is the convolution, multiplied by the original image
#and the bias subtracted
estimator = convolution2*image2.image - convolution3*image2.image
```

Two images for reference: First the 'image2' in the code above; the input image.

[image]

And the final product ('estimator'), with color bar. I would expect this image to be more or less constant, with an average value close to $0.01$. The constancy seems OK, but the value for sure is off.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a SCWE (self contained working example) with plots of the result, and explicitly indicate what seems wrong about it?

Comment: I added an example - hope that helps.

Comment: It's a bit hard to comment on / answer this question because the example is not self-contained, and contains extraneous "stuff": 1) `make_kernel` isn't defined anywhere, 2) `grid` isn't defined anywhere, 3) the windowing step adds complexity; remove it and see if the problem remains, 4) there's no color bar on the first plot. Fixing these issues might lead you to your own solution, and if not it will definitely help me and others understand what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!
I understand that, but that it is simply not possible to include all that in a question on stackoverflow. I will say though, they those aspects of this procedure have been tested extensively.

The core of my question is, really, if the way I compute the integral is OK. If there are no immediate alarm bells ringing when you're reading the post... I think I have my answer.

My apologies for all the hassle...